# Vim Fortran automatic formating with continuation character

Tags: vim

I'm now dealing with a very long expression in Fortran. This code is generated by Mathematica so its really a long one,So how to tell vim to auto wrap line with continuation character "&" auto added to the linebreak?

I have read formatoption but still don't have a idea about how to fix this

very long line example:

```
-(w1*wt00*wt10*metricUcontra(1,1,pdum,tdum))/(3.*h1*h2) - (w1*wt00**2*wt10*metricUcontra(1,1,pdum,tdum))/(3.*h1*h2) - (w1*metricUcontra(1,2,pdum,tdum))/(3.*h1*deltat(-1 + gi)) + (w1*wt00*metricUcontra(1,2,pdum,tdum))/(h1*deltat(-1 + gi)) + (w1*wt00*wt10*metricUcontra(1,2,pdum,tdum))/(h1*deltat(-1 + gi)) + (w1*wt00*wt10*metricUcontraUd(1,1,1,pdum,tdum))/(6.*h1) + (w1*wt00**2*wt10*metricUcontraUd(1,1,1,pdum,tdum))/(6.*h1) + (w1*wt00*wt10*metricUcontraUd(1,2,2,pdum,tdum))/(6.*h1) + (w1*wt00**2*wt10*metricUcontraUd(1,2,2,pdum,tdum))/(6.*h1) + (w1*wt00*wt10*jacobUfd(pdum,tdum,1)*metricUcontra(1,1,pdum,tdum))/(6.*h1*spjac(pdum,tdum)) + (w1*wt00**2*wt10*jacobUfd(pdum,tdum,1)*metricUcontra(1,1,pdum,tdum))/(6.*h1*spjac(pdum,tdum)) + (w1*wt00*wt10*jacobUfd(pdum,tdum,2)*metricUcontra(1,2,pdum,tdum))/(6.*h1*spjac(pdum,tdum)) + (w1*wt00**2*wt10*jacobUfd(pdum,tdum,2)*metricUcontra(1,2,pdum,tdum))/(6.*h1*spjac(pdum,tdum))
```

Comment: Please post this very long expression so that people can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, when I'm pasting it to webpage, it still add backslash, Seems backslash is added by Mathematica...But still have problem in line break with continuation character auto added.